# converting a dataframe to a list, while grouping via key value pairs

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a very simple dataframe:

```
DF <- data.frame(col1=c("a", "a", "b", "b"), col2=c(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

How can I end up with a list that looks like:

```
$a
[1] 1 2

$b
[1] 3 4
```

More importantly, how is this generalizable to some unknown number of groups, beyond `a` and `b`?

I first thought I could use something like `group_by` from the dplyr package, but it only seems to be useful if you are going to then `summarise` or something along those lines.

I think the best idea would be to use `lapply` but I'm not exactly sure how to do the grouping.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this? It may well be avoidable if you tell us more about your context.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be using `split`

```
with(DF, split(col2, col1))
# $a
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $b
# [1] 3 4
```

Or, using indexes (per @jorans comment)

```
split(DF[[2]], DF[[1]])
```

Or

```
split(DF[, 2], DF[, 1])
```

Comment: ...and the requested version by index rather than name: `split(DF[[2]],DF[[1]])`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want:

```
as.list(unstack(DF,col2~col1));
## $a
## [1] 1 2
##
## $b
## [1] 3 4
```

Comment: can I reference the columns by index not name?

Comment: `as.list(unstack(DF,DF[[2]]~DF[[1]]));`